# How do I use options with time?

Tags: unix, time

Whenever I try to use options with the time command, such as format (-f, --FORMAT), I get the following error:

```
bash: -f: command not found
```

How do I use options with time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are invoking the bash's *built-in* version of `time`, which has slightly different behavior and options – described in bash's manual as well as `help time`.

Use `command time ...` to bypass the built-in and execute the external command; or run `/usr/bin/time ...` directly.

Comment: This fixed my issue. I was unaware there was a difference between the man page and bashes version on any of the commands, add that to the things I learned today.

Comment: If it's all settled, click the check mark next to the answer to accept this answer.

Comment: Bash's built-in `type` function will show which you'll run -- e.g. `type time`. Add the `-a` option to show all -- `type -a time`

Comment: @DougHarris I know how to accept an answer, but there is a 15 minute delay between asking and when you can accept.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The downside to getting help so quickly :-)

Comment: As a follow-up, how would I get this to work when running it in a a for loop? For example.. "for i in 1, 2, 3; do command time --format=%e ls" does not seem to work properly, but running the bash version of "time" works as expected.

Comment: It seems just fine here, although you're missing a `; done` at the end.